# Using raw_input inside functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't figure out why `raw_input` isn't being called when I run the function. Instead of being asked `"At bats?"` I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex19a.py", line 9, in <module>
    Slugging()
TypeError: Slugging() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

I know that two arguments are required but I thought I set up the function to use the `raw_input`s as the arguments.

My code is:

```
def Slugging(At_Bats, Total_Bases):
    At_Bats = float(raw_input("At bats?"))
    Total_Bases = int(raw_input("Total Bases?"))
    Percentage = (At_Bats / Total_Bases)

    print "Analysing data..."
    print "Your slugging percentage is %.3f" % Percentage

Slugging()
```

Comment: It would be run if you were successfully calling the function; as the traceback tells you, **you aren't**. Your code fails when it tries to call the function, because you defined two arguments you don't actually pass (and which, if you did pass, you'd immediately shadow with the user input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the parameters from your Slugging function! Your current error is because you are calling the Slugging function with 0 arguments and it expects 2 (At_Bats and Total_Bases).

```
def Slugging():
    At_Bats = float(raw_input("At bats?"))
    Total_Bases = int(raw_input("Total Bases?"))
    Percentage = (At_Bats / Total_Bases)

    print "Analysing data..."
    print "Your slugging percentage is %.3f" % Percentage

Slugging()
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be a stupid mistake. I'd just been looking at it for too long.